# Composite primary Key in Jhipster Entity of Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jhipster

I have a problem with the composite key in Jhipster entity.
This is my example composite key in sql:

`Table Chi_Dinh_Xet_Nghiem:` will receive multiple key from `Phieu_Chi_Dinh_XN` and set it as primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `chi_dinh_xet_nghiem`  (
  `id` bigint(0) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `don_vi_id` int(0) NOT NULL',
  `benh_nhan_id` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `phong_chi_dinh` int(0) NULL DEFAULT,
  `nam` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `don_vi_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `bakb_id`, `nam`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `FK_ChiDinhXN_XetNghiem_IDX`(`xet_nghiem_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `FK_ChiDinhXN_Phong_IDX`(`phong_chi_dinh`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `FK_ChiDinhXN_PhieuChiDinh_idx`(`phieu_chi_dinh_xet_nghiem_id`, `don_vi_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `bakb_id`, `nam`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChiDinhXN_PhieuChiDinh` FOREIGN KEY (`phieu_chi_dinh_xet_nghiem_id`, `don_vi_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `bakb_id`, `nam`) REFERENCES `phieu_chi_dinh_xn` (`id`, `don_vi_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `bakb_id`, `nam`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChiDinhXN_Phong` FOREIGN KEY (`phong_chi_dinh`) REFERENCES `phong` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ChiDinhXN_XetNghiem` FOREIGN KEY (`xet_nghiem_id`) REFERENCES `xet_nghiem` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

`Table Phieu_Chi_Dinh_XN`:

```
CREATE TABLE `phieu_chi_dinh_xn`  (
  `id` bigint(0) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bakb_id` bigint(0) NOT NULL ,
  `benh_nhan_id` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `don_vi_id` int(0) NOT NULL,
  `nam` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `bakb_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `don_vi_id`, `nam`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `FK_PhieuChiDinhXN_bakb_idx`(`bakb_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `don_vi_id`, `nam`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PhieuChiDinhXN_bakb` FOREIGN KEY (`bakb_id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `don_vi_id`, `nam`) REFERENCES `benh_an_kham_benh` (`id`, `benh_nhan_id`, `don_vi_id`, `nam`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

And this is my Jhipster entity, something wrong with entity `Chi_Dinh_Xet_Nghiem` it create duplicate code in DTO, Service, Mapper,...

```
{
  "fluentMethods": true,
  "clientRootFolder": "khamchuabenh",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "nam",
      "javadoc": "Năm",
      "fieldType": "Integer",
      "fieldValidateRules": [
        "required"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityName": "phieuChiDinhXetNghiem",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "chiDinhXN",
      "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
      "relationshipName": "phieucdxn",
      "otherEntityField": "id",
      "options": {
        "id": true
      }
    },
    {
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityName": "phong",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "chiDinhXN",
      "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
      "relationshipName": "phong",
      "otherEntityField": "id"
    },
    {
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityName": "xetNghiem",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "chiDinhXN",
      "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
      "relationshipName": "xetNghiem",
      "otherEntityField": "id"
    }
  ],
  "changelogDate": "20200506034700",
  "entityTableName": "chi_dinh_xet_nghiem",
  "dto": "mapstruct",
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "service": "serviceImpl",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
  "fluentMethods": true,
  "readOnly": false,
  "embedded": false,
  "clientRootFolder": "khamchuabenh",
  "applications": [
    "khamchuabenh"
  ],
  "microserviceName": "khamchuabenh"
}
```

`Phieu_Chi_Dinh_Xet_Nghiem' entity:

```
{
  "fluentMethods": true,
  "clientRootFolder": "khamchuabenh",
  "fields": [
    
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityName": "benhAnKhamBenh",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "phieuCDXN",
      "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
      "relationshipName": "bakb",
      "otherEntityField": "id",
      "options": {
        "id": true
      }
    },
    {
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityName": "benhAnKhamBenh",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "phieuCDXN",
      "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
      "relationshipName": "bakb",
      "otherEntityField": "nam",
      "options": {
        "id": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "changelogDate": "20200506034700",
  "entityTableName": "phieu_chi_dinh_xet_nghiem",
  "dto": "mapstruct",
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "service": "serviceImpl",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
  "fluentMethods": true,
  "readOnly": false,
  "embedded": false,
  "clientRootFolder": "khamchuabenh",
  "applications": [
    "khamchuabenh"
  ],
  "microserviceName": "khamchuabenh"
}
```

But the main problem is **How to let Jhipster understand the Composite Key between multi table?**

Sorry for my bad English and the langue in code. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you used the composite key blueprint? https://github.com/elhoutico/jhipster-composite-key-server-blueprint  You could have used JDL which is easier to read than JSON see an example in blueprint.Composite keys implies copying some properties in DTOs especially for "*-to-one" relationships. Alternatively, it's simpler to use technical key and defining unique key constraints for the business key.

Comment: Are you trying to import legacy database into a JHipster? Or is it a new project starting from scratch?